# Adding to an ArrayList / Searching to see if element exists and then also adding to it

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, addition, contains

Using ArrayList  - I would like to accomplish the following using the adds and contains methods...

Essentially I want to add objects that have shipping prices attached to them ie.

```
B("Baseball Bat", 0.8),
G ("Glove", 0.9),
H ("Helmut", 1.0),
```

If I add $100 worth of Baseball Bats and none are in the list it adds, if baseball bats are already in the list it just adds to the already existent amount...

Any and all insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show some code. Hint: use a map instead of an `ArrayList`

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

A [HashMap](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap) is better suited in order to do this :

```
  HashMap<String,Float> hm = new HashMap<String,Float>();  
  hm.put("Baseball Bat", 0.8);  
  hm.put("Glove", 0.9);
```

and if you want to increment something

```
if(hm.containsKey("Baseball Bat"))
{
    hm.put("Baseball Bat", hm.get("Baseball Bat") + 1.25);
}
```

To get all the values :

```
for ( Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    float f = entry.getValue();
    // do something with key and/or value
}
```

But since you asked for an ArrayList you can put an object in the list.

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Item could have a String field with the name and also a float value for the amount of money.